# Using the WPF hyperlink control with dynamic URLs

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, hyperlink

Disclaimer: I am really new at WPF, so I apologize for the dumb question.

I have a WPF form that contains a hyperlink tag that works fine if the URL is hard-coded into the XAML, like so:

```
    <TextBlock Margin="171,148,129,70">
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.somesite.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock Text="Open site in browser"  />
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

With the following code behind:

```
    protected void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

What I would like to do is make this hyperlink's destination URL dynamic. I have added a new window (invoked as a dialog) to obtain the new link which is then assigned to a private member of the main window's class on its "true" return. How can I adjust the XAML markup/code-behind to use the class member at all times (I'll set to a default in the constructor) instead of hard-coding it into the tag?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the noob question. I must be using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Button styled to look like a Hyperlink and bind the `CommandParameter` to your URL. You'd then set the `Command` to run something like this:

```
public void OpenWebsite(string url)
{ 
    Process.Start(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your hyperlink _requestNavigate method to use that private variable:

```
protected void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(privateVariableName));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```